# Comparing column values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, multiple-columns, difference

I have the following output from a txt file. My goal is to find the difference between values of Column 2 and Column 3 as long as the value in Column 1 remains below or equal to 5, that means my expected output is the difference of Column 2 and 3 values up to Row 5 as the Column 1  value in Row 6 is greater than 5.

1. 1 4 5
2. 2 6 7
3. 3 8 8
4. 4 4 7
5. 5 3 2
6. 6 8 4

I tried the following approach.

```
import pandas as pd
data= pd.read_table('/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A.txt', dtype=float, header=None, sep='\s+').values
x=data[:,0]
y=(data[:,1] for x<=5)
z=(data[:,2] for x<=5)
Diff=y-z
print(Diff)
```

I received this error: (SyntaxError: invalid syntax), any help on how to get it going would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

>>> np.where(data[:, 0] <= 5, data[:, 1] - data[:, 2], np.nan)
array([ -1.,  -1.,   0.,  -3.,  1.,  nan])
```

For your code, you can use a conditional list comprehension:

```
y = [i for x, i in zip(data[:, 0], data[:, 1]) if x <= 5]
z = [i for x, i in zip(data[:, 0], data[:, 2]) if x <= 5]
diff = [a - b for a, b in zip(y, z)]
```

or...

```
diff = [y - z for x, y, z in data if x <= 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try this

```
(df2['v2'].subtract(df2['v3']))[(df2['v1']<=5)]

Out[856]: 
0   -1
1   -1
2    0
3   -3
4    1
dtype: int64
```

*Data input*

```
  df2
    Out[857]: 
       v1  v2  v3
    0   1   4   5
    1   2   6   7
    2   3   8   8
    3   4   4   7
    4   5   3   2
    5   6   8   4
```

Comment: Thanks Wen for your suggestion, i tried this Diff=(data['v2'].subtract(data['v3']))[(data['v1']<=5)] but got this error (IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices)

Comment: @Hrihaan  convert it to `Dataframe` may solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your column names are `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`. Just swap column names with your own

**Option 1**

```
df.query('a <= 5').eval('b - c')
```

**Option 2**

```
df.b.sub(df.c)[df.a.le(5)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, so I need to convert the data into pandas dataframe for it to work?

Answer (score 1):

I think the `SyntaxError` is coming from your generator comprehension, because it doesn't really do anything.  What is being iterated over?

Anyway, you can directly select the rows with column 0 `<= 5` like so:

**EDIT**:  You don't need to convert the DataFrame into a numpy array with `.values`.

```
 import pandas as pd
 data = pd.read_table('/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A.txt', dtype=float, header=None, sep='\s+') # note: no .values
 idx = data[0] <= 5
 Diff = data.loc[idx, 1] - data.loc[idx, 2]
 print(Diff)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried following your way but received this error (AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'loc') in this line (Diff = data.loc[idx, 1] - data.loc[idx, 2]), would you please help me to solve it?

Comment: The reason for the `AttributeError` is because you immediately turned the dataframe into a numpy array when you read it via `.values`.

Comment: I edited my code as the instructions and it worked really well.